# XSLT Display Serial number

Tags: xml, xslt

My input XML consists of the following,

```
<root>
    <entry>
        <type>U</type>
        <value>111</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <type>X</type>
        <value>222</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <type>E</type>
        <value>333</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <type>Q</type>
        <value>444</value>
    </entry>
</root>
```

Output i required,
    `<ROOT>`
        `<ENTRY>`
            `<SLNO>1</SLNO>`
            `<VALUE>111</VALUE>`
        `</ENTRY>`
        `<ENTRY>`
            `<VALUE>222</VALUE>`
        `</ENTRY>`
        `<ENTRY>`
            `<VALUE>333</VALUE>`
        `</ENTRY>`
        `<ENTRY>`
            `<SLNO>2</SLNO>`
            `<VALUE>444</VALUE>`
        `</ENTRY>`
    `</ROOT>`

I need to parse all the records, but need to put serial number for records whose type is not X and E.

I have written a for-each to for the same and used ´position()´ to display a serial number with condtion for type E and X. 
So I'm getting serial number as 1, 4 instead of 1, 2 because of ´postion()´.

I thought of creating a global variable and increment it inside my if block, but XSLT 1.0 will not allow to increment variable values.

How can I achieve this?

My sample XSL code is asl follows,

```
<xsl:for-each select="/ROOT/ENTRY">
    <xsl:if test="(TYPE != 'X') and (TYPE != 'E')">             
        <xsl:text><![CDATA[<SLNO>]]></xsl:text>
        <xsl:number value="position()"/>
        <xsl:text><![CDATA[</SLNO>]]></xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <!-- Printing remaining values -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Please help.

Comment: You might be interested in a solution that is much faster (O(N) - linear) than the currently accepted one (quadratic -- O(N^2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using position(), you could count the number of preceding **type** elements in your XML

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::type[. != 'X' and . != 'E']) + 1" />
```

Additionally, you can simplify your current XSLT by matching the **type** element directly, rather than the **entry** element, and then just replace it with the new **slno** element.

```
<xsl:template match="type[. != 'X' and . != 'E']">
```

For example, try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="type[. != 'X' and . != 'E']">
      <slno><xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::type[. != 'X' and . != 'E']) + 1" /></slno>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="type" />

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<root>
   <entry>
      <slno>1</slno>
      <value>111</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <value>222</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <value>333</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <slno>2</slno>
      <value>444</value>
   </entry>
</root>
```

Note, I am using all lower-case element names here. I wasn't sure from your question if you wanted to translate them into upper-case or not.

Comment: Hi Tim, your solution is correct, but i'm printing lot of fields inside the for-each loop, so i need to keep the for-each.Can you provide another solution that make use of existing for-each loop and instead of value i need '<RESULT>444</RESULT>. Sorry for not mentioning it before.

Comment: Tim, i have used the following inside the for-each and found its working, '<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::CL[. != 'X' and . != 'E']) + 1" />' Thanks a lot

Comment: TimC: This is a good answer, but may be slow (O(N^2) -- quadratic time complexity) with big number N of `entry` elements. You might be interested in a solution that has linear time complexity (O(N)).

Comment: Hi Dimitre, Thanks a lot for the response and seems like your concern is valid. But in my case number of ENTRY tags will be very less, max 15.So currently i'm following @Tim's approach. Thanks a lot for your valuable time

Comment: @user1442391: Of course. Whenever you have a realworld processing task with a large input size, then algorithm complexity becomes of major importance. Even if you don't need a linear algorithm now, you may need it in the near future -- in this respect it is good to be aware that you aren't using the most efficient algorithm and that it is possible to experience very slow execution in future runs. I have witnessed a case where a 40 minutes transformation was reduced to 2 seconds just changing its quadratic algorithm to Muenchian grouping (sublinear).

Answer (score 0):

**The accepted answer is a good one, except that the implemented algorithm has O(N^2) (quadratic) time complexity and executes very slow on large inputs**.

**Here is transformation with linear-time-complexity O(N):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:param name="pCount" select="0"/>
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*">
     <xsl:with-param name="pCount" select="$pCount"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]">
     <xsl:with-param name="pCount" select="$pCount"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="entry[not(contains('EX', type))]">
  <xsl:param name="pCount" select="0"/>

  <xsl:copy>
   <slno><xsl:value-of select="$pCount+1"/></slno>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*">
     <xsl:with-param name="pCount" select="$pCount+1"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]">
     <xsl:with-param name="pCount" select="$pCount+1"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="type">
   <xsl:param name="pCount" select="0"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]">
     <xsl:with-param name="pCount" select="$pCount+1"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <entry>
        <type>U</type>
        <value>111</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <type>X</type>
        <value>222</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <type>E</type>
        <value>333</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <type>Q</type>
        <value>444</value>
    </entry>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<root>
   <entry>
      <slno>1</slno>
      <value>111</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <value>222</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <value>333</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <slno>2</slno>
      <value>444</value>
   </entry>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Using and overriding the **["fine-grained identity rule"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5694777/36305)**. It bears its name due to the fact that templates are applied only to one node (in document order) at a time.
2. The "fine-grained identity rule" is modified to contain and pass a parameter `$pCount`, which contains the maximum current "serial number" reached so far.
3. This works without the need to return back the current serial number, because all `entry` elements are siblings.
4. The time complexity is linear, because there is no counting of all preceding siblings at every node, as done in the other answer.