# XSLT - Explode Nodes on a delimiter

Tags: xml, xslt

I need an XSLT 1.0 that breaks down XML nodes on a delimiter and creates individual nodes.
For example, if the delimiter is '_' and the XML is:

```
<root>
    <a_b_c>hello<a_b_c>
    <a_b_c1>world</a_b_c1>
</root>
```

the result XML should be:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b>
            <c>hello</c>
            <c1>world</c1>
        </b>
    </a>
</root>
```

Nodes that do not contain the delimiter, should be outputted as is.
I really need this in XSLT1.0
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="kSameNameAdj" match="*"
  use="concat(generate-id(..),
              '+',
              generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(name()=name(current()))][1])
              )"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)" mode="compress"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="explode" match=
  "*[contains(name(),'_')
   and not(substring(name(),1,1)='_')
   and not(substring(name(), string-length(name()))='_')
    ]">
    <xsl:param name="pName" select="name()"/>
    <xsl:param name="pText" select="text()"/>

  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="not($pName)">
    <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:element name="{substring-before(concat($pName, '_'), '_')}">
       <xsl:call-template name="explode">
         <xsl:with-param name="pName" select="substring-after($pName, '_')"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$pText"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="fold" mode="compress">
  <xsl:param name="pDoc" select="/"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not($pDoc//*[name()=name(following-sibling::*[1])])">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$pDoc"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:variable name="vrtfThisPass">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$pDoc/*" mode="compress"/>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:call-template name="fold">
        <xsl:with-param name="pDoc" select="ext:node-set($vrtfThisPass)"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="compress">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[1]" mode="compress"/>
   </xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]" mode="compress"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[name()=name(following-sibling::*[1])]" mode="compress">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="compress" select=
    "key('kSameNameAdj',
          concat(generate-id(..),
                 '+',generate-id(preceding-sibling::*)
                 )
         )/node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="compress" select=
  "key('kSameNameAdj',
          concat(generate-id(..),
                 '+',generate-id(preceding-sibling::*)
                 )
         )
          [last()]/following-sibling::node()[1]
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (the provided one, extended to be more challenging):

```
<root>
   <x>This is:</x>
     <a_b_c>hello</a_b_c>
     <a_b_c_d>my</a_b_c_d>
     <a_b_c1>wonderful</a_b_c1>
     <a_b_c>world</a_b_c>
     <a_b>!</a_b>
   <y>The End</y>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<root>
   <x>This is:</x>
   <a>
      <b>
         <c>hello<d>my</d>
         </c>
         <c1>wonderful</c1>
         <c>world</c>!</b>
   </a>
   <y>The End</y>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

.1. **This is a multi-pass transformation**. 
The first pass transforms the XML document into:

```
<root>
   <x>This is:</x>
   <a>
      <b>
         <c>hello</c>
      </b>
   </a>
   <a>
      <b>
         <c>
            <d>my</d>
         </c>
      </b>
   </a>
   <a>
      <b>
         <c1>wonderful</c1>
      </b>
   </a>
   <a>
      <b>
         <c>world</c>
      </b>
   </a>
   <a>
      <b>!</b>
   </a>
   <y>The End</y>
</root>
```

.2. **The consequent passes, each compresses any group of adjacent elements with the same name into a single element with that name** -- then the result is processed recursively until there is no more any group of more than one adjacent siblings elements having the same name.

.3. **The first pass uses the [identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.

.4. **The next passes use the [fine-grade identity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5694777/36305) template** in "compress" mode.